# Send input to a running shell script using stdin fd

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to send command to a running shell script via his stdin file descriptor. The script should display the command that has been received.

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    echo "line is $line"
done
```

The script works with keyboard input but doesn't when I send value to his stdin fd as :

```
$ echo "foo" > proc/XXX/fd/0
```

The value "foo" is displayed in the terminal where I launched my script, but not catch by the it. Am I doing it wrongly ? Is there an other way to send the command ?

Comment: pty is not used for usual inter-process communication. what problem are using solving?

Comment: I would like to send "foo" to the running script via a command or an other script

Comment: does `echo foo | /your/script.sh` work for you?

Comment: It works but only for starting the script. I would like to do the same on a script already running